# Purpose of fitting parallel lines

Tags: r, regression, fitting

I'm a student. I have a dataset of a set of observations split across three factors/categories. I'm being asked to fit three regression-lines with identical slope (but different intercepts, obviously).

What's the purpose of parallel lines? To optimize what slope performs best for all three categories?

Comment: It is not really clear what you are asking. Could you describe your problem in greater detail?

Comment: Do the three lines correspond to three different groups?

Comment: @Tim I modified the question. Is that better? This is the extent of the information that I have. It's not a very good book, and the teacher is worse.

Comment: @DustinOprea I think you have to go into greater detail because I am not sure if I understand your question correctly.